# Multiple forms and submit buttons, but only one gets submitted?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 forms on one page, and each form has a submit button.

I need each button to only submit the form its assigned to.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Here's the code:

```
<body>

    <?php 

        include ("test.txt")

    ?>

    <br> <br>
    <form name = "contactForm" action = "php/text_write.php" method = "post">

        <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "text_input">Replace this text with what you want to print on screen</textarea> <br> <br>  
        <input type= "submit" name = "write_text" value = "Edit Text!">

    </form>


</body>
```

```
<body>

    <form action="php/upload/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <label for="file">Filename:</label>


    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>


    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit">

</body>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that forms to this by default. Perhaps the lack of name in the second form is playing trickery on you? Also after the comment from Jitendra, why do you have two body tags in your HTML?

Comment: Your second form is not close close `</form>` tag first. :)

Comment: Missing closing form tag `</form>` for the second form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 2nd form to this

```
<body>

<form action="php/upload/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<label for="file">Filename:</label>


<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>


<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve what you want in pure HTML. Reason is that when user hits submit button browser must prepare HTTP POST request. Contents of this request is defined by  fields of the form where submit button is pressed. Then browser required to accept HTTP response, destroying contents of another form in the process.

However you can use javascript to do what you need. You may use form submit method but not allow your browser to navigate away from your page. This way HTTP POST from particular form will reach the webserver. However webserver response will be ignored. Technically will do what you want but will be absolutely terrible user experience. Hence I am not going to delve into technical details how to achieve it and you should use single form with single submit button for all elements in all forms.

Another way to solve it and have multiple forms (and I personally don't like such solution) is to use frames where each frame has its own form and submit button. Frames will provide level of independence for the forms. But please note that frames are not really welcome these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single submit button to control two forms in html, it is every form with its submit button.

So your code for your forms should change to;

First Form:

```
<?php 

    include ("test.txt")

?>

<br> <br>
<form name = "contactForm" action = "php/text_write.php" method = "post">

    <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "text_input">Replace this text with what you want to print on screen</textarea> <br> <br>  
    <input type= "submit" name = "write_text" value = "Edit Text!">

</form>
```

Your Second Form

```
<form action="php/upload/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <label for="file">Filename:</label>


    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>


    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit">

</form>
```